# Add Mozilla root certs to Windows without admin

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, pem

I want to add [Mozilla's root certs](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1) to Windows 7 without admin privileges.

Is there a straight forward way to add the root certificates into the current user's certificate store?  I'd prefer to use Windows' native tools, without relying on something I'd have to download.

Some resources that looked promising.

- [Pre-converted PEM files by CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) - The Mozilla root certs converted to PEM and hosted by cURL.  Here's a direct link to the [PEM Encoded root certs](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)
- [Verified HTTPs in Ruby](http://notetoself.vrensk.com/2008/09/verified-https-in-ruby/) - A general overview of how to obtain the root certificates.
- [How to get root certs for cURL](https://gist.github.com/jjb/996292) - explains how to generate the PEM file from the Mozilla certificates yourself.
- [How to Import Certificates using Powershell](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/james/powershell-ing-on-windows-server-how-to-import-certificates-using-powershell/) - a ranting overview of how to install certificates that seems more complex than it ought to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended making a powershell script to do it.

**VERIFY THIS CODE BEFORE RUNNING IT.**  It's adding all of the certificate authorities from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem to the current user's **TRUSTED ROOT** certificate store.

To run it in a single command, paste the following into a command prompt:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.github.com/jschaf/install-mozilla-certs/master/install-mozilla-cert.ps1'))"
```

Here's the Github link: https://github.com/jschaf/install-mozilla-certs

And the source:

```
# Variables
$url = "http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem"

# Download the certificates
Write-Host "Downloading Mozilla certificates from $url."
$downloader = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$rawcerts = $downloader.DownloadString("http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem")

# Remove headers and begin/end delimiters and convert into a byte
# stream
$header = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`n"
$footer = "`n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
$match_string = "(?s)$header(.*?)$footer"
$certs_matches = Select-String $match_string -input $rawcerts -AllMatches
$certs_base64 = $certs_matches.matches | %{ $_.Groups[1].Value }
$certs_bytes = $certs_base64 | %{ ,[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($_) }

# Install the certificates
$user_root_cert_store = Get-Item Cert:\CurrentUser\Root
$user_root_cert_store.Open("ReadWrite")
foreach ($c in $certs_bytes) {
    $cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(,$c)
    $user_root_cert_store.Add($cert)
}
$user_root_cert_store.Close()
Write-Host "Finished installing all certificates."
```

One annoying thing is that Windows will prompt for yes/no for every certificate.  Since it's installing 158 certificates this gets old quick.  If anyone knows how to prevent confirmation let me know or drop a pull request.

Comment: Per [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196997/certificate-install-security-warning-workaround), there's no way to bypass the confirmation prompts if you're not an administrator installing certificates into the local machine's store.