# How can we avoid the security prompt while installing the Fiddler core certificate

Tags: c#, .net, fiddler, fiddlercore

i am using fiddler core to trace all the Request's but my problem is i am doing all this in windows service and i don't want the security prompt to come while installing the fiddler core root certificate how can i disable it and auto install the certificate without the prompt.

[image: Fiddler core root certificate installation prompt]

Comment: All I can say is I truly hope there's no way to dodge that dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Certificate Install Security Warning Workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196997/certificate-install-security-warning-workaround)